# Trouble with javascript sweetalert alertbox

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am using sweetalert (http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) for popping up alert messages instead of using standard javascript alert box. I have installed necessary libraries. It functions only on certain conditions but fails to appear on some other. This code:

```
if (document.getElementById('a').value == "") {
    swal("Error","The value is empty.");
    return false;
} else {
..
..
}
```

works fine, as expected. However, if I code like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('a').value == "") {
    swal("Error","The value of A is empty.");
    return false;
}
if (document.getElementById('b').value == "") {
    swal("Error","The value of B is empty.");
    return false;
} 
if (document.getElementById('c').value == "") {
    swal("Error","The value of C is empty.");
    return false;
}
```

only the last message (C) pops up even when all values are empty. Does anyone have experience with sweetalert who can help me?

Comment: Are you sure that `a` and `b` are both really empty? (i.e. not a string of white space) If all three are empty that code should alert that `a` is empty and not show any others messages due to the `return false` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked the source code briefly, but my guess would be that the Sweet Alert box is overridden. You're using 3x `if` statements, but no `if else`. So when the 2nd condition is hit, the first error box is overridden, and when the 3rd condition is hit, the second error box is overridden.

So if sweet alert only support one error box at a time, you will need to arrange the conditions so the most important error is last.

Comment: When a series of conditions have to be evaluated irrespective of the other values, then if else if may not be needed. What is the way around?

Comment: Actually your original code is probably the way to go. It just seems that sweet alert will override the alerts, so you can only show one alert to the user. In your code you attempt to show the user 3 alerts, and it takes the last one. Does that make sense?